# Chroma key webcam video with gstreamer

Tags: linux, video, gstreamer, fedora

I'm trying to put together a green screen application with my Logitech C910 WebCam on Fedora 21. I've managed to get 1080p30 h264 video from the webcam to be displayed with gstreamer using the following command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! queue ! \
    video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! \
    h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! xvimagesink sync=false
```

This is working great with nice and low latency. The next thing I want to do is Chroma Key-ing of the picture making certain colours transparent before I add an image / video behind the webcam picture. From what I've read I need to use the alpha filter to achieve this. From looking at gst-inspect I can see that it takes in video/x-raw and outputs video/x-raw. The avdec_h264 element outputs video/x-raw so it looks like I should be able to do:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! queue ! \
    video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! \
    h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! alpha method=green ! \
    xvimagesink sync=false
```

However whenever I run that command I get the following output:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Redistribute latency...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2933): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 0:00:00.437613774
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing and why this isn't working correctly?

Thanks in advance for any help,

Mrs Kensington

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should connect *alpha* with *xvimagesink* via **videoconvert** element:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! queue ! \
video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! \
h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! alpha method=green ! videoconvert ! \
xvimagesink sync=false
```